# Elastic Search : Does it maintain inverted and non inverted indexes both internally?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

I was reading about elastic search. It looks like it maintain inverted index on all terms in all the documents. But does it also maintain normal indexing, i.e. from document id to document? Also, as it maintains lot of indexing on all fields and for all terms, so does it take too much memory? 
Eg. when compared to DynamoDb, where say, I made indexes on only 2 fields and here it form indexes on each and every term, which would be more memory efficient?

Comment: By default, ES indexes every field, but it can also be tuned to only index the exact same two fields as you index with DynamoDB. You'd need to do that in order to have a meaningful comparison between ES and DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

"too much" is a very opinionated question and will totally depend on your use-case. To make an informed decision, you'll need to dive into a few topics (Elasticsearch is really powerful, but you need to know what you are doing):

- [Text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) vs [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)
- [Meta-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html) especially `_all` and `_source`
- Every  [`_uid` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-uid-field.html), which contains the `_id`, is indexed.

So it will really depend on your data, your mapping, and what you want to achieve with your data. I'm afraid you will need to build a quick prototype with exactly your data and use-case to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamo and ES are very different beasts.  A few examples:

1. in ES, you can specify how to index every field and search on every field.
2. in Dynamo, you can only have up to 5 indexes, everything else is a full scan
3. in ES, you control your cluster settings
4. Dynamo the "cluster" is managed for you, but you need to be really smart about how you partition your data.
5. in ES, you can query for exactly what you want, do aggregations on the server, get stats, really cool stuff.
6. in Dynamo you can't even do an "order by"